# col/bg for plotting ecdf

Tags: r, plot

I would like to highlight certain points (without the adjacent lines) in an ecdf plot. The problem is, that either
a) using `col`, the lines left of these points get labelled as well: [image: ecdf_coldescription here]
b) using `bg` has absolutely no effect even if specifying a `pch` that normally uses bg: [image: ecdf_bg]
Where is my mistake? Is there an easy way to do that (other then to extract the ecdf function data and create the plot by hand)? I prefer plain plotting over ggplot etc. Thanks in advance!

```
set.seed(seed=123)
dta=rnorm(20)
plot(1:2, pch=c(19, 25), col="blue", bg="red", cex=5, lwd=4) 
# works perfectly (note: pch=19 only has col, no bg, whereas others (e.g. 25) have col (border) and bg (fill))  

# a)        
plot(ecdf(dta), pch=19, col=c("gray","red"))  
# colored symbols AND lines, but I only want to color the symbols (see 1st figure above)

# b)    
plot(ecdf(dta), pch=25, col="gray",bg="red")  
# specifying bg does not work from plot.ecdf (see 2nd fig. above)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
set.seed(seed=123)
dta=rnorm(20)
##
plot(ecdf(dta), pch=19, 
    col="gray",
    col.01line = "gray")
lines(ecdf(dta),col="gray",
      col.points=c(
        rep(c("gray","red"),20)))
##
```

[image]

**EDIT**: even easier (without the additional `lines` call) incorporating at the aditional parameters available for `plot.stepfun` directly:

```
# nonsense colors, just to illustrate the possibility to set further parameters:
? plot.stepfun # has many more parameters!!
plot(ecdf(dta), pch=19, 
     col="blue",
     col.points=c(
       rep(c("gray","red"),20)),
     verticals=TRUE, col.vert="pink",
     col.01line = "green")
```

Comment: Thanks - this works for me, even if I still do not understand why bg is ignored...?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know exactly why it is being ignored either, but I can possibly give you a workaround? Save your current global plot settings with `opar <- par()`, then change the global setting of `bg` with `par(bg="red")`, and carry on with your plotting. When you want to reset to defaults just call `par(opar)`.

Comment: The call to the points function in `plot.stepfun` (called by `plot.ecdf`)ignores the bg parameter: `points(xval, Fn.kn, pch = pch, col = col.points, cex = cex.points)`. It would be very simple task to hack a replacement function.